# Mapping arrays between C++ and Fortran

Tags: c++, fortran

I have a project which successfully maps a C++ structure to a Fortran equivalent.  The structure contains arrays.  On the C++ side, the arrays in the structure are represented as:

```
struct t_res_p {
  double *p_length = nullptr;
  double *p_diam = nullptr;
}
```

and on the Fortran side:

```
type :: t_res_p_ext
  sequence
  real(8), pointer :: p_length
  real(8), pointer :: p_diam
end type t_res_p_ext
```

Which works fine.  I have been recommended to use vectors on the C++ side, but when I use this:

```
struct t_res_p {
  CDArray p_length;
  CDArray p_diam;
}

( CDArray is std::vector<double> )
```

The call from C++ is as follows:

```
t_res_p p_res;

p_res.p_length.SetSize(ns,0.0);
p_model(&p_res);
```

And on the Fortran side:

```
subroutine p_model(p_res) bind(C)
  type(t_res_p_ext), target, intent(inout) :: p_res
...
```

The Fortran structure does not match up.  Seems like I need to add .data() somewhere although I'm not sure of the syntax.

Comment: You may use the `std::vector::data()` member function to retrieve a pointer for interacting with the fortran code.

Comment: thanks, but I still need to map something on the C++ side to the Fortran structure - do I need to create a new C++ structure containing the data() members?

Comment: Your current Fortran way is really ugly. I don't even understand how it could work. `real(8), pointer :: p_length` is a pointer to one single real. Not to an array. Fortran array pointers are not interoperable with C. Fortran has a whole rich set of features for Fortran-C interoperability. See, e.g., [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding]. Also, kind 8 does not have to correspond to C double. The linked module has the `c_double` constant for that.

Comment: there is a difference between `REAL*8` and `REAL(8)`, the former is size of type - an obsolete way, the latter is the "kind" of type.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава As long as the length is known on both sides it works just fine.

Comment: @Adrian Well I can see how it might work after some dirty tricks, e.g. by passing the scalar to an external subroutine, because a scalar pointer is normally just implemented using an address in Fortran, but you it is not just "just fine", you have to create something that points to an array on the Fortran side. `real(8), pointer :: p_length` is a scalar, not an array and Fortran is not C where often an array and an address are the same things. Anyway, there is way too little information in the question. You talk about some structures, but you do not show any.

Comment: If `p_length` is a `vector<double>`, then `plength.data()` is a `double*` that you can directly pass to the Fortran routine. That said I concur with @VladimirFГероямслава that your Fortran side is ugly, and it works by chance. The most appropriate way is to declare `real(c_double) :: p_length(n)` (n being past as well) and use all the C binding features (including for the structures): this will ensure a much better portability.

Comment: The main difference between `real*8` and `real(8)` is the former is not and has never been part of standard Fortran, while the latter *is* standard Fortran, but *not* portable.

Comment: @PierU the trouble is that I pass a structure containing all these arrays, not the arrays by themselves.  So the whole structure needs to match on both the C++ and Fortran sides.  So I have to use and send them as std::vector.  Unless there is trick to use only the data() bit in the declaration syntax within the structure.

Comment: I say again, your question does not show anybstructures nor the way how you pass them between C++ and Fortran. There is no way to answer this.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I have updated the question with the structures

Comment: This is way too little. the point is showing how you pass that from C++ to Fortran and you make it to point to an array in Fortran. But the most likely solution is to just pass a proxy structure with the data pointers, not the original structure itself. This is commonly done even for much more complicated object and even when one does the proper C-Fortran interoperability instead of dirty tricks. BTW, `sequence` structures are not C-interoperable and there is no guarantee that the C++ compiler will align  the structure components in the same way.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава  C++ / Fortran calls added

Comment: Just use a proxy object.  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72972139/passing-complex-data-structures-between-fortran-and-c  But in your case you just make the class like your original `t_res_p` and you set the pointers to point to the `.data()` pointers for those vectors that live somewhere else.

Comment: The drawback is that the data pointer can change during the lifetime of the vector. You will be responsible to update the pointers in the proxy. You will not be to pass anything that contains a C++ vector directly without some complicated compiler and platform specific code.

Comment: This question should be reopened

Comment: @PierU not sure how to do that, nor why it was closed in the first place ...  in the meantime I have successfully created a proxy structure on the C++ side which contains the double * arrays which point to the data part of the CDArray vectors.  The former maps into the Fortran structures and all works fine.

Comment: Only people with more than 2000 reputation can vote for reopening a question I think.